# Grid view setting the back ground color

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, colors

I am dynamically setting the back ground color of some of the cells present in the grid view.
The issue is when I scroll down incorrect colors are set as background for some of the cells. I am recycling view.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder= new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
        holder.textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //System.out.println("the position is "+position);

    Date i = objects.get(position);

    try
    {
        if (i.getDate() == 1) 
        {
            holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.textView.setText("Mon"+Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Can some one guide me how to handle this issue ?

update 1 : I solved the issue 
           I just added the following statement in the else part

```
        if (i.getDate() == 1) 
        {
            holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.textView.setText("Mon"+Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
            holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
```

Comment: hi can you post your you model class ?
or can you tell me what is "objects" in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
holder.textview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
try
{

 if (i.getDate() == 1) 
    {
        holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        holder.textView.setText("Mon"+Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
    } 
    else 
    {
        holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(i.getDate()));

    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

 holder.textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View view = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView==null)
    {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId,parent,false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text);
        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder= (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    //System.out.println("the position is "+position);

    Date i = objects.get(position);

    try
    {
        if (i.getDate() == 1) 
        {
            holder.textview.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            holder.textView.setText("Mon"+Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
        } 
        else 
        {
            holder.textView.setText(Integer.toString(i.getDate()));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return view;
}
```